# jshell : Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, java-11, jshell

I run this `/edit` command in jshell java-11,When throw the exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I'm using `Debian 9.0` operating System.

Exception image

[image: jshell> /edit]

Comment: `DISPLAY` is an environment variable used by the [X Windows System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). If you search the Internet for "X Windows DISPLAY environment variable", you should find how to set it. Your error message implies that your java code references classes in `java.awt` package, either directly or indirectly. Excuse me but I couldn't see your java code in your post. Did I miss something?

Comment: jshell> /edit
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: @Abra this Exception generated in jshell, not java code.

Comment: @Abra Please read the question.

Comment: The `/edit` command in _JShell_ tries to open an editor window. In order to do that it assumes that an X windows server is running. Is that the case?

Comment: Hint: cursing doesn't help and isn't appreciated here. And you still didn't tell us about your setup. Are you running some gnome or kde desktop, and have a terminal doing this, or are you ssh'ing into your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the following things come together:

- you are running jshell in a way that prevents it from starting/raising your *preferred* editor
- that preference is determined from looking at some environment variables (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/editing.htm#GUID-EA504020-D68D-4396-B67C-32C6736894BE) for names/order)

Thus, a simple solution could be: set the JSHELLEDITOR environment variable to something that doesn't require a X window, like vi for example.